# How can I map/change/implements methods from one layer to another?

Tags: java, spring, methods, service, layer

Good evening, I'm learning about using layers in the spring and I've encountered some problems that I don't know how to solve...

I know that the entity is exposed in the Repository, where we use Hibernate to perform operations.
In the service layer we have to use an Object to "hide" the entity, but how do we map Classes / Entities by methods?

I mean, we have this example, but I want to use JPA, and I can't use a ProductData id to search to a Product Repository, for example, how can I modify these methods to work without errors, please?

```
public ProductData findById(Integer id){
        ProductEntity product = productRepo.findById(id);
        ProductData data = new ProductData(product.getId(), product.getName(), product.getCeva());
        return data;}
```

Comment: You can use a mapper like [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) or [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) to convert objects.

Comment: Hello, but is the only way to do like that, and is oke or accepted or expected to doing like this when you working with big projects?

Comment: These tools are definitly an option, but it's also a bit tricky to configure them properly. Can be a lot of magic happen there, so a plain method copying over values can be enough. You may look at a project https://bootify.io , it's doing exactly this.